# WL-Proxy-Client-Cert header not sent

Tags: apache, servlets, weblogic, reverse-proxy

I m using Oracle HTTP Server as reverse proxy for WebLogic.  I have set up SSL on both the proxy and the server with client certificate authentication.  It works and the clients get authenticated by OHS, but i need to pass client certificate information to WebLogic so i can look at this certificate in my servlet.  Documentation says that the proxy can forward client certificate within "WL-Proxy-Client-Cert" http header to the WebLogic server.

However, i can't get this to work.  Within my servlet i tried both request.getHeader() and request.getAttribute() and getting null.  I looked at both headers and attributes of the request objects and don't see anything like WL-Proxy-Client-Cert.  In fact i don't see any headers starting with WL, only couple of headers starting with X-WebLogic, none of which has the certificate.

I did enable "Client Cert Proxy Enabled" option in Administration Console as described in the docs.  Also i know that clients get authenticated since i see the certificate requested by the browser, after which i can successfully access the site.

Am i missing something?

Comment: That sounds like WebLogic is authenticating baed on the client certificate... so what is the problem, you want some of the cert info available to your Servlet as well? With Client Cert Proxy Enabled checked it should be available with getAttribute I think; I assume you activated the change?

Comment: I activated the change.  I also checked in the debugger, i don't see it neither in headers nor attributes.  Since the my weblogic server itself has client certificate authentication, i do get certificate in "javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate" attribute, but this is the certificate of the proxy itself, not the client.  What i need is to get the client certificate.

Comment: Also, as suggested somewhere, i enabled WLProxySSL and WLProxySSLPassThrough directives in the plugin configuration, but unfortunately that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally got an answer from Oracle support on this.  The problem was that i had to add one SSL directive to my virtual host configuration:

SSLOptions +ExportCertData

It goes under "IfModule ossl_module", right next to "SSLVerifyClient require" directive that specifies 2-way authentication for the proxy.

Note that after this, in the servlet, the certificate will be present in the usual "javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate" attribute, as if the server was doing client certificate authentication itself (no extra headers are received).

Also, note that you can have the server use 1-way SSL, if you feel secure with authentication done by the proxy, and you will still receive the certificate in the attribute in your servlet (in this case you should probably add a filter as they recommend to ensure the requests come from the proxy only).  I have a feeling it will work even if the server port is regular http, though i haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Yes, it works even if the connection between the proxy and WebLogic is plain HTTP (I used apache with the WL plugin as the proxy).